# Kubernetes and external DNS

Tags: kubernetes, dns, bind, external-dns

i have a lab environment with a bind server. The server manages the domain "lab.local" DNS Dynamic Update are configured. The lab client (windows and linux) are using the DNS server.

Now i would like do use a kubernetes cluster in our lab. Can i use the bind server with the zone "lab.local" with kubernetes?

For example: i would like to create a nginx pod and access it from my client over nginx.lab.local. I have looked at https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns but i didn't find any Information how to use it with bind.

Answer (score 3):

Once the nginx Pod has been created, it will have a internal IP by default, not addressable from your lab network (only other pods can access it).

To access it from the lab network, expose it as a Service with type as [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) and then it will have a external routable IP address. Then add an entry in the bind server to that external routable IP address for everyone to access using the URL.

There are other and better ways also of exposing a Service by using a [Load Balancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) or an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/). For those who are new or getting started with K8S, exposing the Pod using NodePort is the easiest to see some quick results.

Comment: thanks you for your answer. i have exposed the port and created the record  manually in the bind dns. Is the are possibility to easy add the external bind dins to K8S?